# Reading Makefile variables in golang when building Android

Tags: go, makefile, android-source

In `device/vendor/rules.mk` we have couples of flags. For example:

```
INCLUDE_VENDOR_PACKAGES:=true
```

I am writing a go package to do some conditional operation based on above flag. I tried couples of ways to fetch this flag's value such as via Golang's `os` package API and via `$` operator like we do in shell script. But none of these worked.

Is there anyway to fetch the flag from `Makefile` at build time in `go` packages?

Comment: Make a global variable  `var INCLUDE_VENDOR_PACKAGES = ""`. Inside build script add `--ldflags "-X main.INCLUDE_VENDOR_PACKAGES=${FLAG}"` as a parameter for build. (Instead of main may be path of package where variable is located)

Comment: I gave that variable as one of the example. It might be possible that there are many variables on which I would need to write Golang conditional implementation. This approach would need a lot of unnecessary code addition. @LaevusDexter

Answer (score 0):

Make variables are internal to `make`.<sup>*</sup>  They are not (directly) exposed to the recipes running in rules (or to commands run by GNU function implementations).  You need to make explicit provision for feeding these values to commands that `make` runs, generally either by explicitly placing the wanted values into individual commands' environments or by passing them as command-line arguments to those commands.

---

<sup>*</sup> However, one place that `make` obtains variable values is from like-named environment variables, which will also be available under some circumstances to commands that `make` runs in turn.

Comment: I think there should be a Android way since Android Build system uses Makefile, Blueprint and Golang together. For reference check this mapping of some of the commonly used Makefile keys mapping in Golang, [**here.**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/refs/heads/master/androidmk/androidmk/android.go?autodive=0%2F#43)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, that there is a shared vocabulary for build properties does not in any way imply that `make` automatically exposes those data to build recipes it runs, which is what would be needed for anything that I could characterize as the commands in a recipe fetching such data *from the Makefile*, as you asked.  No doubt there is a mechanism for conveying such information through Android's broader build framework -- environment variables would still be my guess -- but that does not change the answer to the question posed.